# WinForms: ListView's BackgroundImage positioning

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I've put a BackgroundImage on my ListView in one of my windows forms.

Everything works as expected. But now I'd only like to position this image inside the ListView.

Like in CSS: `background-position: top right;` Would stick the image at the top right corner of the element.

Is there any way of doing so with a windows form?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't.

[This blog](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog1.html) documents why `LVM_SETBKIMAGE` and intercepting `WM_ERASEBKGROUND` do not work with .NET ListViews.

The solution I found for this problem -- and which is used in the [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) project -- is to use the low-level custom draw facilities of the native ListView control. It was complicated to implement, but is (now) easy to use.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, so yes, you can. Put on the resize or anywhere else if you don't resize listview

(need some optimize I guess, dont know)

```cs
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(listView1.Width, listView1.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                SolidBrush br1 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                g.FillRectangle(br1, 0, 0, listView1.Width, listView1.Height);
                g.DrawImage(Image, listView1.Width - Image.Width, listView1.Height - pictureBox1.Image.Height);
            }
            listView1.BackgroundImage = bmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way I know is to inherit from ListView and override the OnPaintBackground methode and draw the Image with Graphics.DrawImage() on your own. But you have to calculate the position on your own ;) You can also add a costum property for the aligment of the type System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.

Comment: OnPaintBackground doesn't run, painting is done by the native Windows control.

Answer (score 0):

otherwise you can tile the image , but it wont be stuck in one place .

listView1.BackgroundImageTiled = true;